# Use a pattern to get a specific to extract a specific part of a string in R

Tags: html, r, text-mining, stringr, rcurl

I have a dataframe which contains an "URL" column and an "extract from a review" column. I want to get the complete reviews from the websites, without getting the rest of the html code.

I would need R to locate the extract in the html code and then extract all of the text delimited by the previous "<div" the next "/div>". This would look like:
(unwanted text) <div (...) extract (...) /div> (unwanted text)

this is the attempt I tried

```
library(XML)
library(xml2)
library(RCurl)
library(stringr)
df$Review <- str_extract_all(RCurl::getURL(df$Link, ssl.verifypeer = TRUE),paste0(c("^(<div).{1,1000000}"),paste(df$Estratto),c(".{1,1000000}(/div>)")))
```

The problem with this may be that I'm telling R to extract strings that start with "<div" and end with "/div>", not "extract the complete div class which contains my string".

How can I procede?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
library(stringr)
st
[1] "<divwww.google.com/div>" "<divwww.yahoo.com/div>" 
str_extract(st, '(?<=div)(.*)(?=/div>)')
[1] "www.google.com" "www.yahoo.com"
```

Comment: It is a great improvement but it doesn't solve the problem. In fact this would work if there is just one "<div" and one "/div>", which is not the case. I uptdated the original post so it is a little bit clearer. I would like to extract from the closest "<div" and "/div>" from the extract

Comment: @emmecicubo, Could you post a sample string values that you have?

Comment: If you mean a sample string from the base text, that would be the complete html code of a website, if you mean the code after I used the suggestion you made, here it is!

https://pastebin.pl/view/c9c5cdf6